# How would I return a class from a function that doesn't have a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, smart-pointers, copy-constructor

I'm using boost Asio, and the following function will not compile.

```
udp::resolver Create_UDP_Socket(){
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::socket s(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 0));
    udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    return resolver;
}
```

error: use of deleted function

> boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver::basic_resolver(const
>   boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver&)

what would be the best way to return the resolver?  Is there something I can do with move semantics, or should I make a pointer to the resolver and return that? (what kind: shared/unique?)

**EDIT:
this works:**

```
std::shared_ptr<udp::resolver> Create_UDP_Socket(){
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::socket s(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 0));
    std::shared_ptr<udp::resolver> resolver(new udp::resolver{io_service});
    return resolver;
}
```

I'm still curous if it is possible to return the class without making a pointer to it.

Comment: If you use a somehow recent version of boost and C++11, that should work.

Comment: Are you sure the resulting `resolver` object can be used? The `io_service` is passed to the ctor as a reference and AFAIK it doesn't claim ownership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid copying the object by returning a *smart pointer* to the one object.

```
boost::shared_ptr<udp::resolver> Create_UDP_Socket(){
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::socket s(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 0));
    return boost::shared_ptr<udp::resolver>( new resolver(io_service) );
}
```

A `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` would work too.